# After docker build . the container is not displayed, why?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a docker container with [log.io](https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io).
If I manually run:

```
docker run -it node:argon -p 28777:28777 -p 28778:28778 -p 8000:80 /bin/bash
```

and manually run inside the command which you see in the Dockerfile then everything works perfectly and I am able to log into the service using http.

```
FROM node:argon

WORKDIR Logz.io/src/

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu

#RUN mkdir /root/.log.io \
#       && touch /root/.log.io/harvester.conf \
#       && touch /root/.log.io/log_server.conf \
#       && touch /root/.log.io/web_server.conf

#RUN chmod g+rwx /root/logzio
RUN apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y vim net-tools

RUN npm install log.io

RUN /node_modules/log.io/bin/log.io-server &

RUN /node_modules/log.io/bin/log.io-harvester &

EXPOSE 28777
EXPOSE 28778
EXPOSE 8000
```

But if I run:

```
docker build .
```

The container is created, everything is installed but:

> 1. When the creation finishes and I run `docker ps -a`, the container is not displayed (even though I get it's details when I run `docker inspect`).
> 2. The Log.io service is unavailable when I browse to it through http.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Docker build does not create a container, it creates an image.

If you do:

```
docker build -t "myimage:0.1" .
```

Then do

```
docker run -it myimage:0.1 -p 28777:28777 -p 28778:28778 -p 8000:80 /bin/bash
```

it will instantiate a container based on the image you just built.

Answer (score 1):

When you finish building an `image` from a Dockerfile, a container will not be readily available. You will need to create a `container` *from* the `image` that was created

You can see your images with the command `docker images`

From this list of images, you can create your container via `docker run ...`

If your docker container is not visible after running it, something is likely failing in your build and that would stem from your Dockerfile.

Comment: After doing as you said, a container is created properly but when i'm inside it I see that the node services are not running, got an idea why?

Comment: You may need to use ENTRYPOINT and CMD, take a look here at this Flask example, http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html.

This setup which is presented would generate a running Flask server when the container is created. Alternatively you can explicitly execute the server in your `docker run ... ` command.

I don't use NPM that much, but this should translate the same.